# Postgres: how do you round a timestamp up or down to the nearest minute?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a postgresql function that will return a timestamp rounded to the nearest minute? The input value is a timestamp and the return value should be a timestamp.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Use the built-in function `date_trunc(text, timestamp)`, for example:

```
select date_trunc('minute', now())
```

**Edit:** This truncates to the *most recent* minute. To get a *rounded* result, add 30 seconds to the timestamp first, for example:

```
select date_trunc('minute', now() + interval '30 second')
```

This returns the *nearest* minute.

See [Postgres Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html) for more info

Comment: +1 for the smart trick of adding half of the interval and then truncating.

Answer (score 23):

Answer to a similar (and more generic) question,

> "... to the **nearest minute interval**"  (1-minute, 5-minutes, 10-minutes, etc.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION round_minutes(TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, integer) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE AS $$ 
  SELECT 
     date_trunc('hour', $1) 
     +  cast(($2::varchar||' min') as interval) 
     * round( 
     (date_part('minute',$1)::float + date_part('second',$1)/ 60.)::float 
     / $2::float
      )
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION round_minutes(TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, integer,text) 
RETURNS text AS $$ 
  SELECT to_char(round_minutes($1,$2),$3)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

SELECT round_minutes('2010-09-17 16:23:12', 5);
-- 2010-09-17 16:25:00

SELECT round_minutes('2010-09-17 16:23:12', 10, 'HH24:MI');
-- 16:20
```

Adapted from  http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Round_time and to the "exact round" as @CrowMagnumb showed.

Answer (score 8):

In trying to use Peter's answer above to create ceiling and floor functions I found that you have to take into account the seconds too when calling the rounding function.  This here are my sets of functions that will round, floor, and ceiling timestamps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_minutes( TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, integer) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE AS $$ 
  SELECT date_trunc('hour', $1) + (cast(($2::varchar||' min') as interval) * round( (date_part('minute',$1)::float + date_part('second',$1)/ 60.)::float / cast($2 as float)))
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION floor_minutes( TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, integer ) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE AS $$ 
    SELECT round_minutes( $1 - cast((($2/2)::varchar ||' min') as interval ), $2 );
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ceiling_minutes( TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, integer ) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE AS $$ 
    SELECT round_minutes( $1 + cast((($2/2)::varchar ||' min') as interval ), $2 );
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Comment: Thanks to the correction (!) and extension: now we have a complete "aproximate minutes" library. PS: I think you can add a `int DEFAULT 5` (second parameter) to simplify the most frequent use.

Comment: Ops, another issue: use `LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE`.

Comment: This is not entirely correct: every odd 10 minute interval (10, 30, 50) will floor to the interval below it.
e.g. `select floor_minutes('2022-12-14 22:30:00', 10);` returns `2022-12-14 22:20:00` while `select floor_minutes('2022-12-14 22:20:00', 10);` returns `2022-12-14 22:20:00`

Answer (score 5):

to round down a timestamp

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION date_round_down(base_date timestamptz, round_interval INTERVAL) 
RETURNS timestamptz AS $BODY$
            SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT(epoch FROM date_trunc('hour', $1))::INTEGER + trunc((EXTRACT(epoch FROM $1)::INTEGER - EXTRACT(epoch FROM date_trunc('hour', $1))::INTEGER) / EXTRACT(epoch FROM $2)::INTEGER) * EXTRACT(epoch FROM $2)::INTEGER) 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;

SELECT date_round_down('2017-06-02 16:39:35', '15 minutes') -- 2017-06-02 16:30:35
```

Comment: It doesn't round down the 35 seconds though, which I think is expected

Comment: i tried using this to round to every 2 hours. doesn't work.