# How to return a list of users who should be notified of an appointment at a set time each day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a list of users who need to be notified at different times per day, and based on their timezone.

So I have essentially 2 tables:  Schedule and User

```
Schedule
-id
-scheduled_time

Users
-id
-schedule_id
-timezone
```

**So there could be a schedule for 9AM.
Users who are associated with this 9AM schedule, by they also have their timezone set to UTC -4 or UTC -5.**

I will have a service that will Poll every x minutes to query the database.

Is this a query I can perform in postgresql directly or is this application dependant and based on the ORM I am using?

Comment: What are the datatypes on the columns?

Comment: Please, even losing, as you "attracted answer with bounties", comment each one (where we fail).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing timestamps for time of day just sounds annoying and I recommend doing it from your Rails models.

If you're dead set on doing it from the database, see this question: [Convert a UTC timezone in postgresql to EST (local time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341060/convert-a-utc-timezone-in-postgresql-to-est-local-time/36341459), and here's another article describing how to work with time zones in postgres: http://blog.untrod.com/2016/08/actually-understanding-timezones-in-postgresql.html.

But my sense is you'll get a simpler and easier solution if you use ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone maths, in order to associate each user with a given UTC time at which to notify them.

Example:

Schedule X runs at 16:00 UTC and schedule Y runs at 17:00 UTC.

User A is in UTC-0700 (PDT) and User B is in UTC-0600 (Mountain).

If B wants to be notified at 10:00 AM, then do the math in your application in order to associate them with Schedule X.
If A wants to be notified at 10:00 AM, then do the math in your application in order to associate them with Schedule Y.

Let me know if you would need help with the specifics.  Hints:

- The Time of Day gem offers a nice way to work with times of day, including time zone maths.

  - https://github.com/jackc/tod
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

Answer (score 0):

> I will have a service that will Poll every x minutes to query the database.
>
> Is this a query I can perform in Postgresql directly ... ?

Yes, you can. Imagine the use of the PostgreSQL-server time (function `now()` or `current_timestamp`)  something as

```
SELECT u.*  
FROM schedule s INNER JOIN users u 
  ON u.schedule_id=s.id 
WHERE now()::time=(s.scheduled_time+u.timezone)
```

But, as we will see, the *"every x minutes"* can't sync with the Schedule table. There are two ways for sync:

1. using `<=` and updating the table with a boolean day-flag at users (cleaning every day after 24hs to re-scheduling). No risk.
2. using `=` with a [round(time,x) here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963684/287948)... Perhaps with a very little risk when your hypothesis of *"every x minutes"* is not perfect.

Lets simulate all the thing:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (id serial PRIMARY KEY,  scheduled_time time);
INSERT INTO schedule (scheduled_time) VALUES 
   (now()), ('9:00AM'::time), ('16:30'::time);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial,
  schedule_id int references schedule(id),
  timezone interval  -- see pg_timezone_names.utc_offset
);
INSERT INTO users (schedule_id,timezone) VALUES
 (2, '00:00:00'::interval), (2, '-04:00:00'::interval), (1, '-05:00:00'::interval),
 (1, '-05:00:00'::interval), (1, '-04:00:00'::interval), (2, '-05:00:00'::interval);

CREATE VIEW vw_user_scheduled AS
SELECT u.*, s.scheduled_time, s.scheduled_time+u.timezone AS ref_time
    FROM schedule s INNER JOIN users u 
      ON u.schedule_id=s.id 
;
```

The samples `vw_user_scheduled` are:

```
 id | schedule_id | timezone  | scheduled_time  |    ref_time     
----+-------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------
  1 |           2 | 00:00:00  | 09:00:00        | 09:00:00
  2 |           2 | -04:00:00 | 09:00:00        | 05:00:00
  3 |           1 | -05:00:00 | 20:54:27.898109 | 15:54:27.898109
  4 |           1 | -05:00:00 | 20:54:27.898109 | 15:54:27.898109
  5 |           1 | -04:00:00 | 20:54:27.898109 | 16:54:27.898109
  6 |           2 | -05:00:00 | 09:00:00        | 04:00:00
```

Supposing you adopt the round-solution and `x=5` (service that will Poll every 5 minutes to query the database), the users of scheduled_time 9AM (server time) will be not the set {id=1, id=2 and id=6} as column `scheduled_time`  shows, but only user id=1 of the correct ref_time.

```
SELECT * from vw_user_scheduled 
WHERE round_minutes(ref_time,5)=round_minutes(now(),5)
```

---

The [cited round time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963684/287948) adapted to time datatype.

```
CREATE FUNCTION round_minutes(time, integer) RETURNS time AS $$ 
  SELECT 
     date_trunc('hour', $1)::time 
     +  (cast(($2::varchar||' min') as interval) 
         * round( 
            (date_part('minute',$1)::float + date_part('second',$1)/ 60.)::float 
            / $2::float
         ))
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

---

PS: as **the question not show your SQL table**, there are many ways to model time and time zone formats at tables.